# How to call a prompt that selects a date range when I create a table using proc sql?

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I would like to ask how to call a prompt (I am using SAS Enterprise Guide) in a proc sql that creates a table. 
I am interested in  associate a number to date month (as in the table below) where d_month can be selected by using the prompt.

```
time_window       d_month     database_name   table_name    short_name    group_field               field                  field_list
        1         '2018-02-28'       Dtb1         table1       Tab1        date_month department      Tab1.id Tab1.balance   id balance
        1         '2018-02-28'       Dtb1         table2       Tab2        date_month                  Tab2.credit            credit
        ...
        2         '2018-03-31'       Dtb1         table3       Tab3        date_month department       Tab3.debit             debit
        2         '2018-03-31'       Dtb2         table4       Tab4        date_month department    ...
```

I used

```
   proc sql noprint;
    select time_w into time_w_lower from &time_table..time_table where time_last="&time_win_min_end"d;
    quit;

    proc sql noprint;
    select time_w into time_w_upper from &time_table..time_table where time_last="&time_win_max_end"d;
    quit;
```

to create the minimum and maximum date (and this should be the same of the prompt), but I do not know how to use this information when I select the fields for a new table. 
Time and date month (`d_month`) are in one table (`&time_table..time_table`), whereas the other fields are in another one (`&dtb..&input.`). 
What I tried is:

```
   proc sql;
    create table table_test4 as
    select t.time_window
           ,t.d_month
           ,&alias..date_month
           ,&alias..department
           ,%qsysfunc(dequote(&_factor.))
    from &dtb..&input. &alias.
    cross join time_window t
    order by 1,2,3,4;
    quit;
```

where `time_window` is the table created as follows:

```
  data time_window (drop=i);
      attr time_window length=8 format=11. informat=11.;
      attr d_month length=14 format=$12. informat=$12.;
      do =&time_w_lower. to time_w_upper.;
        time_window=left(put(i,4.));
        d_month=CAT("'", put(intent('month',"01JAN2010"d, i-1, 'end'), YYMMDDD10.),"'");
        output;
      end;
    run;
```

Unfortunately I have no data that I can show, so any example you will provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should create promt with data range type:
   [image]
2. Add created prompt to your node.
   [image]
3. Then you can use generated macro variables from this prompt.
   To know what variable was generated you can run:

   ```
    %put _ALL_;
   ```

> GLOBAL DATE_MAX 31Dec2019
>
> GLOBAL DATE_MAX_LABEL December 31, 2019
>
> GLOBAL DATE_MIN 01Dec2019
>
> GLOBAL DATE_MIN_LABEL December 01, 2019

So, in `proc sql` you can use `"&DATE_MAX."d` and "`&DATE_MIN."d` whete DATE is your prompt name.